# Monorepos, Typescript, Transitive dependencies, and package managers (pnpm)

Tags: typescript, monorepo, transitive-dependency, pnpm

So I just bootstrapped a monorepo using rush (pnpm).

I have a library called `web-commons` that has dependencies "
`fastify`, and others.

I have a backend application called `my-app`.

I want to use certain `fastify` types and modules in `my-app`, but I cannot import it.

How can I make `web-commons` dependencies be included in `my-app` dependencies transitively?

I know part of the problem here is the fact that pnpm uses symlinks, and I like it, makes much more.

But I don't want to declare same dependencies in every backend application I have in the monorepo, and there will be more... so... is there a way?